# Проблема преобразования числа в строку через intl расширение php

Tags: php

При преобразовании числа в строку с помощью кода:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter("ru_RU", \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$a =  $formatter->format($number);
```

для значение выше 16383 с вещественной частью (.1 .2 .3 .7 .8)
возвращает вещественную часть со значением "миллионов стомиллионных"

Например:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter("ru_RU", \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $formatter->format(21234.1);
```

> возвращает значение "двадцать одна тысяча двести тридцать четыре целых
> десять миллионов стомиллионных";

Comment: а как надо? используй другой стиль вывода NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL вот все константы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: Нужно выводить корректно, т.е для числа 21234.1 значение должно вернуться такое "двадцать одна тысяча двести тридцать четыре целых одна десятая". Другой стиль вывода не подходит